# How to scale the speed of a moving object for each update on the screen according to fps so it can be the same moving speed at any given fps?

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

I was making a game on Python3 using Pygame and PyOpenGL. When I test the game on different computers, they all run the code at a different fps and pace.

Sample code:

```
#...
while True:
    character.x += 5
    character.draw()
    pygame.display.flip() #Updates the screen
```

Since some computer can run through the loop more times and some less, the x position of the character will be different at a certain time after running the code on two computers at the same time. How can I get the current fps on the screen and get a scalar that scales the speed of the object according to the fps?

Thanks in advance,

Noah

Comment: I would use the real-time delay between updates to calculate position.  Using the FPS assumes that all environments can achieve that frame rate.  This isn't guaranteed, especially if some heavy process is running in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of a [pygame.time.Clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) and then call [Clock.tick](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) once every loop to set the framerate and get the elapsed time

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    delta = clock.tick(60) # 60 FPS
```

Multiply your movement speeds by this delta for a smooth and consistent animation (you may need to reduce the delta value here as it's milliseconds elapsed which can be large)

```
    character.x += 5 * delta
```